# Hazelcast new members not joining existing cluster

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hazelcast

I am trying to use Hazelcast in a Spring Boot application on my local. But it seems that each instance is starting up separately(without any errors) and not joining into the existing member list.

Instance 1:

```
Members {size:1, ver:1} [
    Member [10.111.130.204]:5701 - 6d4a2864-5c90-4063-a2cc-deb64a950622 this
]
```

Instance 2:

```
Members {size:1, ver:1} [
    Member [10.111.130.204]:5702 - 196c9d1f-7fd4-4c48-8dec-0fb913671610 this
]
```

I followed the guideline found here to setup a simple environment https://guides.hazelcast.org/hazelcast-embedded-springboot/

Can someone help figure out what am I missing here?

---

PS:

I also tried creating below configs, still the same behaviour.

```
    @Bean
    public Config hazelCastConfig() {
        Config config = new Config();
        config.getNetworkConfig().setPortAutoIncrement(true);
        config.getGroupConfig().setName("hazelcast-cluster");
        config.setManagementCenterConfig(new ManagementCenterConfig().setEnabled(true).setUrl("http://localhost:8080/hazelcast-mancenter"));
        NetworkConfig network = config.getNetworkConfig();
        JoinConfig join = network.getJoin();
        join.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(true);
        return config;
    }

    @Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance(Config hazelCastConfig) {
        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(hazelCastConfig);
    }
```

---

Sample Logs[Instance 1]

```
2021-12-15 18:08:06.186  INFO 38768 --- [           main] com.example.hzdemo.HzDemoApplication     : Starting HzDemoApplication
2021-12-15 18:08:06.192  INFO 38768 --- [           main] com.example.hzdemo.HzDemoApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-12-15 18:08:07.776  INFO 38768 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2021-12-15 18:08:07.783  INFO 38768 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-12-15 18:08:07.783  INFO 38768 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.55]
2021-12-15 18:08:07.854  INFO 38768 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-12-15 18:08:07.854  INFO 38768 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1542 ms
2021-12-15 18:08:07.943  WARN 38768 --- [           main] c.h.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory    : Hazelcast is starting in a Java modular environment (Java 9 and newer) but without proper access to required Java packages. Use additional Java arguments to provide Hazelcast access to Java internal API. The internal API access is used to get the best performance results. Arguments to be used:
 --add-modules java.se --add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED
2021-12-15 18:08:07.966  INFO 38768 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker     : [LOCAL] [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] Prefer IPv4 stack is true, prefer IPv6 addresses is false
2021-12-15 18:08:07.985  INFO 38768 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker     : [LOCAL] [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] Picked [10.111.130.204]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5701], bind any local is true
2021-12-15 18:08:07.994  INFO 38768 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.system                     : [10.111.130.204]:5701 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] Hazelcast 3.12.6 (20200130 - be02cc5) starting at [10.111.130.204]:5701
2021-12-15 18:08:07.994  INFO 38768 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.system                     : [10.111.130.204]:5701 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] Copyright (c) 2008-2020, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
2021-12-15 18:08:08.208  INFO 38768 --- [           main] c.h.s.i.o.impl.BackpressureRegulator     : [10.111.130.204]:5701 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] Backpressure is disabled
2021-12-15 18:08:08.576  INFO 38768 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [10.111.130.204]:5701 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] Creating MulticastJoiner
2021-12-15 18:08:08.676  INFO 38768 --- [           main] c.h.s.i.o.impl.OperationExecutorImpl     : [10.111.130.204]:5701 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] Starting 16 partition threads and 9 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
2021-12-15 18:08:08.678  INFO 38768 --- [           main] c.h.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics     : [10.111.130.204]:5701 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to the JVM arguments.
2021-12-15 18:08:08.686  INFO 38768 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [10.111.130.204]:5701 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] [10.111.130.204]:5701 is STARTING
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.SelectorOptimizer (file:/Users/<user>/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.hazelcast/hazelcast/3.12.6/7640af720dfb86de81d93617271e2959dea6bfdc/hazelcast-3.12.6.jar) to field sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.selectedKeys
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.SelectorOptimizer
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2021-12-15 18:08:11.096  INFO 38768 --- [           main] c.h.internal.cluster.ClusterService      : [10.111.130.204]:5701 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] 

Members {size:1, ver:1} [
    Member [10.111.130.204]:5701 - 6d4a2864-5c90-4063-a2cc-deb64a950622 this
]

2021-12-15 18:08:11.111  INFO 38768 --- [           main] c.h.i.m.ManagementCenterService          : [10.111.130.204]:5701 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] Hazelcast will connect to Hazelcast Management Center on address: 
http://localhost:8080/hazelcast-mancenter
2021-12-15 18:08:11.117  INFO 38768 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [10.111.130.204]:5701 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] [10.111.130.204]:5701 is STARTED
2021-12-15 18:08:11.389  INFO 38768 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
2021-12-15 18:08:11.404  INFO 38768 --- [           main] com.example.hzdemo.HzDemoApplication     : Started HzDemoApplication in 5.715 seconds (JVM running for 6.731)
2021-12-15 18:08:12.126  INFO 38768 --- [.MC.Task.Poller] c.h.i.m.ManagementCenterService          : [10.111.130.204]:5701 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] Failed to pull tasks from Management Center
2021-12-15 18:08:12.126  INFO 38768 --- [MC.State.Sender] c.h.i.m.ManagementCenterService          : [10.111.130.204]:5701 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] Failed to connect to: http://localhost:8080/hazelcast-mancenter/collector.do
2021-12-15 18:08:12.126  INFO 38768 --- [MC.State.Sender] com.hazelcast.client.impl.ClientEngine   : [10.111.130.204]:5701 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] Applying a new client selector :ClientSelector{any}
```

Sample Logs[Instance 2]

```
2021-12-15 18:09:06.831  INFO 39059 --- [           main] com.example.hzdemo.HzDemoApplication     : Starting HzDemoApplication
2021-12-15 18:09:06.843  INFO 39059 --- [           main] com.example.hzdemo.HzDemoApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-12-15 18:09:07.943  INFO 39059 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8082 (http)
2021-12-15 18:09:07.953  INFO 39059 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-12-15 18:09:07.954  INFO 39059 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
2021-12-15 18:09:08.024  INFO 39059 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-12-15 18:09:08.024  INFO 39059 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1047 ms
2021-12-15 18:09:08.162  INFO 39059 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker     : [LOCAL] [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] Prefer IPv4 stack is true, prefer IPv6 addresses is false
2021-12-15 18:09:08.188  INFO 39059 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker     : [LOCAL] [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] Picked [10.111.130.204]:5702, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5702], bind any local is true
2021-12-15 18:09:08.213  INFO 39059 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.system                     : [10.111.130.204]:5702 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] Hazelcast 3.12.6 (20200130 - be02cc5) starting at [10.111.130.204]:5702
2021-12-15 18:09:08.213  INFO 39059 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.system                     : [10.111.130.204]:5702 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] Copyright (c) 2008-2020, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
2021-12-15 18:09:08.490  INFO 39059 --- [           main] c.h.s.i.o.impl.BackpressureRegulator     : [10.111.130.204]:5702 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] Backpressure is disabled
2021-12-15 18:09:08.917  INFO 39059 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [10.111.130.204]:5702 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] Creating MulticastJoiner
2021-12-15 18:09:09.101  INFO 39059 --- [           main] c.h.s.i.o.impl.OperationExecutorImpl     : [10.111.130.204]:5702 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] Starting 16 partition threads and 9 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
2021-12-15 18:09:09.104  INFO 39059 --- [           main] c.h.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics     : [10.111.130.204]:5702 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to the JVM arguments.
2021-12-15 18:09:09.107  INFO 39059 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [10.111.130.204]:5702 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] [10.111.130.204]:5702 is STARTING
2021-12-15 18:09:11.423  INFO 39059 --- [           main] c.h.internal.cluster.ClusterService      : [10.111.130.204]:5702 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] 

Members {size:1, ver:1} [
        Member [10.111.130.204]:5702 - 196c9d1f-7fd4-4c48-8dec-0fb913671610 this
]

2021-12-15 18:09:11.424  WARN 39059 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [10.111.130.204]:5702 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] Config seed port is 5701 and cluster size is 1. Some of the ports seem occupied!
2021-12-15 18:09:11.451  INFO 39059 --- [           main] c.h.i.m.ManagementCenterService          : [10.111.130.204]:5702 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] Hazelcast will connect to Hazelcast Management Center on address: 
http://localhost:8080/hazelcast-mancenter
2021-12-15 18:09:11.460  INFO 39059 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [10.111.130.204]:5702 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] [10.111.130.204]:5702 is STARTED
2021-12-15 18:09:11.620  INFO 39059 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-12-15 18:09:11.761  INFO 39059 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8082 (http) with context path ''
2021-12-15 18:09:11.765  INFO 39059 --- [           main] com.example.hzdemo.HzDemoApplication     : Started HzDemoApplication in 5.854 seconds (JVM running for 6.337)
2021-12-15 18:09:12.470  INFO 39059 --- [.MC.Task.Poller] c.h.i.m.ManagementCenterService          : [10.111.130.204]:5702 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] Failed to pull tasks from Management Center
2021-12-15 18:09:12.470  INFO 39059 --- [MC.State.Sender] c.h.i.m.ManagementCenterService          : [10.111.130.204]:5702 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] Failed to connect to: http://localhost:8080/hazelcast-mancenter/collector.do
2021-12-15 18:09:12.471  INFO 39059 --- [MC.State.Sender] com.hazelcast.client.impl.ClientEngine   : [10.111.130.204]:5702 [hazelcast-cluster] [3.12.6] Applying a new client selector :ClientSelector{any}
```

ifconfig output:

```
utun2: flags=80d1<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST> mtu 1390
    inet 10.111.130.204 --> 10.111.130.204 netmask 0xffffc000
```

Comment: Which version are you using? Do you confirm that you're running on your machine or are you running in a containerized environment?

Comment: Is multicast enabled on the host ?

Comment: @Nicolas hazelcast versions tried `com.hazelcast:hazelcast:3.12.6` and `com.hazelcast:hazelcast-all:4.1`. Yes, i am running it on my local machine, not containerized environment.

Comment: @NeilStevenson As part of the above config, i am enabling it. Not sure how to verify the same on host. Let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: There might be something indicative in the logs, if you could post them from both processes. You could always use [TCP](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.0/clusters/discovering-by-tcp) to progress, and figuring out the cause here becomes less urgent. `ifconfig` might be a start to finding the cause, if your host has it.

Comment: @NeilStevenson I have updated the question with the logs for both processes along with the `ifconfig` output.

Comment: @NeilStevenson Using the TCP config, it worked.

Comment: You're using a VPN? 1390 seems an non-default MTU. Perhaps something a networking guru or forum can help with -- if you need multicast discovery. Multicast is only used for discovery, after that it's TCP anyway.